# How can I download multiple files (50+ at a time) in vanilla JS by simulating mouse clicks in code?

Tags: javascript, download, click, href

I am working on a chrome extension that allows me to quickly download log files that display as a series of links on the page. I have a function that looks like this:

```
function downloadAll() {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll(DOWNLOAD_ID);

    for (link of links) {
        link.click();
    }
}
```

Download ID is something such as "#IWantToDownloadThis" that I previously added to the anchor tag elements to be able to query for all of them. And then each element in the list of links has the right href value pointing to the file I want to download. I can download the files one by one by clicking on them, but when I try to do something like the above it only downloads the first file, and never more than one. What am I doing wrong/how can I fix this to actually download each file? I am not very familiar with much JS so I am probably doing something obviously wrong but haven't found any answers to solve my problem

I tried the code as seen above. I would expect it to iterate through the anchor tags in the list, simulate clicking on each one which would download a file when done. What actually happens is the first link gets "clicked" on by my code, but then no other links are clicked on and so only 1 file downloads.

Comment: By clicking on the link you are probably changing page. If you can run code, can you extract the url and use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?